# Blank page with primefaces/jsf with chrome and safari (and yes - I have f:view)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm getting a blank screen with Primefaces/JSF with Safari and Chrome.

I have the following in my code - so it's not the one that's been asked 1000 times:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3c.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<f:view contentType="text/html">

<h:head>
...

</p:layout>
</h:form>
</h:body>
</f:view>
</html>
```

Also, some pages on my app work just fine and some don't.

I think this has something to do with the carousel since chrome has a uncaught TypeError in the primefaces.js line that starts with

```
PrimeFaces.widget.Carousel=..
```

Any ideas on what this is and how to proceed with fixing it greatly appreciated.

Line 7 that all the browsers are reporting the error on is:

```
PrimeFaces.widget.Carousel=PrimeFaces.widget.BaseWidget.extend({init:function(b){this._super(b);this.viewport=this.jq.children(".ui-carousel-viewport");this.header=this.jq.children(".ui-carousel-header"),this.list=this.viewport.children("ul");this.items=this.list.children(".ui-carousel-item");this.prevButton=this.header.children(".ui-carousel-prev-button");this.nextButton=this.header.children(".ui-carousel-next-button");this.pageLinks=this.header.find(".ui-carousel-page-links .ui-carousel-page-link");this.dropdown=this.header.children(".ui-carousel-dropdown");this.state=$(this.jqId+"_first");this.cfg.numVisible=this.cfg.numVisible||3;this.cfg.pageLinks=this.cfg.pageLinks||3;this.cfg.effect=this.cfg.effect||"slide";this.cfg.effectDuration=this.cfg.effectDuration||500;this.cfg.easing=this.cfg.easing||"easeInOutCirc";this.cfg.pageCount=Math.ceil(this.items.length/this.cfg.numVisible);this.cfg.firstVisible=(this.cfg.firstVisible||0)%this.items.length;this.cfg.page=(this.cfg.firstVisible/this.cfg.numVisible)+1;this.animating=false;var c=this.items.filter(":first"),a=c.get(0);this.cfg.itemOuterWidth=c.innerWidth()+parseInt(this.getProperty(a,"margin-Left"))+parseInt(this.getProperty(a,"margin-Right"))+((parseInt(this.getProperty(a,"border-Left-Width"))+parseInt(this.getProperty(a,"border-Right-Width"))));this.cfg.itemOuterHeight=c.innerHeight()+Math.max(parseInt(this.getProperty(a,"margin-Top")),parseInt(this.getProperty(a,"margin-Bottom")))+((parseInt(this.getProperty(a,"border-Top-Width"))+parseInt(this.getProperty(a,"border-Bottom-Width"))));if(this.cfg.vertical){this.viewport.width(this.cfg.itemOuterWidth);this.viewport.height(this.cfg.numVisible*this.cfg.itemOuterHeight)}else{this.viewport.width(this.cfg.numVisible*this.cfg.itemOuterWidth);this.viewport.height(this.cfg.itemOuterHeight)}this.jq.width(this.viewport.outerWidth(true));this.setOffset(this.getItemPosition(this.cfg.firstVisible));this.checkButtons();this.bindEvents();if(this.cfg.autoplayInterval){this.startAutoplay()}},getProperty:function(a,b){return $.browser.msie?a.currentStyle.getAttribute(b.replace(/-/g,"")):document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(a,"").getPropertyValue(b.toLowerCase())},startAutoplay:function(){var a=this;if(this.cfg.autoPlayInterval){setInterval(function(){a.next()},this.cfg.autoPlayInterval)}},bindEvents:function(){var a=this;this.pageLinks.click(function(b){if(!a.animating){a.setPage($(this).index()+1)}b.preventDefault()});PrimeFaces.skinSelect(this.dropdown);this.dropdown.change(function(b){if(!a.animating){a.setPage(parseInt($(this).val()))}});this.prevButton.click(function(b){if(!a.prevButton.hasClass("ui-state-disabled")&&!a.animating){a.prev()}});this.nextButton.click(function(){if(!a.nextButton.hasClass("ui-state-disabled")&&!a.animating){a.next()}})},getPagePosition:function(a){return -((a-1)*(this.cfg.vertical?this.cfg.itemOuterHeight:this.cfg.itemOuterWidth)*this.cfg.numVisible)},getItemPosition:function(a){return -(a*(this.cfg.vertical?this.cfg.itemOuterHeight:this.cfg.itemOuterWidth))},getPosition:function(){return parseInt(this.list.css(this.cfg.vertical?"top":"left"))},setOffset:function(a){this.list.css(this.cfg.vertical?{top:a}:{left:a})},fade:function(b){var a=this;this.list.animate({opacity:0},{duration:this.cfg.effectDuration/2,specialEasing:{opacity:this.cfg.easing},complete:function(){a.setOffset(b);$(this).animate({opacity:1},{duration:a.cfg.effectDuration/2,specialEasing:{opacity:a.cfg.easing},complete:function(){a.animating=false}})}})},slide:function(c){var a=this,b=this.cfg.vertical?{top:c}:{left:c};this.list.animate(b,{duration:this.cfg.effectDuration,easing:this.cfg.easing,complete:function(){a.animating=false}})},next:function(){this.setPage(this.cfg.page+1)},prev:function(){this.setPage(this.cfg.page-1)},setPage:function(a){if(this.cfg.circular){this.cfg.page=a>this.cfg.pageCount?1:a<1?this.cfg.pageCount:a}else{this.cfg.page=a}this.checkButtons();this.state.val((this.cfg.page-1)*this.cfg.numVisible);var b=this.getPagePosition(this.cfg.page);if(this.getPosition()==b){this.animating=false;return}if(this.cfg.effect=="fade"){this.fade(b)}else{this.slide(b)}},checkButtons:function(){this.pageLinks.filter(".ui-icon-radio-on").removeClass("ui-icon-radio-on");this.pageLinks.eq(this.cfg.page-1).addClass("ui-icon-radio-on");this.dropdown.val(this.cfg.page);if(this.cfg.circular){return}if(this.cfg.page==1){this.prevButton.addClass("ui-state-disabled")}else{this.prevButton.removeClass("ui-state-disabled")}if(this.cfg.page>=this.cfg.pageCount){this.nextButton.addClass("ui-state-disabled")}else{this.nextButton.removeClass("ui-state-disabled")}}});
```

Thanks, 
-Dave

Comment: The `<f:view>` is not required in Facelets at all. This myth is a leftover of old JSP era. As to the JS error, are you manually including any script files? If so, which ones? If not, are you sure that you've only one PrimeFaces JAR file in the webapp's runtime classpath (and thus not multiple different versioned ones)?

Comment: Just one JAR of primefaces - 3.5. I do have two versions of commons-lang jar (2.4 and 3.1) but the second one is recent and the problem has been around before. No script files. The TypeError in chrome is reported on primefaces.js.jsf?ln=primefaces:7 (Cannot call method 'getPropertyValue' of null) and ln-primefaces:1 (Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'refresh').

Comment: IE 8 shows errors in the same lines - in line 7 'currentStyle' is null or not an object and line 1 as Object doesn;t support this property or method.

Comment: Which JS files are been downloaded according to HTTP monitor? (network tab in Chrome web dev tools)

Comment: And firefix has an error on the same line (but renders the page) as - NotSupportedError: Operation is not supported.

Comment: Carousel may not be the issue - I am changing the carousel into a dataTable and the line 7 error is gone but have the line 1 error (object #HTMLDivElement> has no method 'refresh'. The function on line 1 is indeed some kind of handler for duplicate executions of primefaces -- but where am I getting two from?

Comment: Sorry, but the symptoms described so far still suggests that multiple copies of jQuery library are being loaded. Looking into the HTTP monitor should give confirmation. I asked that in my previous comment, but you didn't give any feedback on that. If you didn't understood me, just say that so instead of ignoring it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a posting by optimus.prime and this resolves it - the answer is that when you have dialogs the widgetVar should be different than the id - otherwise safari and chrome do not render the page.

I.e. bad:

```
<p:dialog id="tabbedJoinedD" widgetVar="tabbedJoinedD" ...
```

Good:

```
<p:dialog id="tabbedJoinedD" widgetVar="tabbedJoinedDV" ...
```